# Jquery colorbox and Js email validation integration

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a form that is inside a colorbox pop over and when i submit the form i want to see the next page (where the form is posted) right inside the same pop over so i found this script that works for that matter.

```
$("#botonsiguiente").click(function () { // ATTACH CLICK EVENT TO MYBUTTON
$.post("/envioypago-prueba2.php",        // PERFORM AJAX POST
$("#frmSS11").serialize(),      // WITH SERIALIZED DATA OF MYFORM
  function(data){                // DATA NEXT SENT TO COLORBOX
    $.colorbox({
      html:   data,
      open:   true,
      iframe: false            // NO FRAME, JUST DIV CONTAINER?
    });
  },
  "html");
  });
```

But the problem is that i have another JS script on the same page that performs the email validation on the form and they dont work together becuase when i submit the form the form is posted without validation.

What i wan to do is to integrate the two scripts so the email validation is done BEFORE the form is posted.

The exact JS script that i use for the email validation is the following one.

```
// <![CDATA[

        function CheckMultiple11(frm, name) {
            for (var i=0; i < frm.length; i++)
            {
                fldObj = frm.elements[i];
                fldId = fldObj.id;
                if (fldId) {
                    var fieldnamecheck=fldObj.id.indexOf(name);
                    if (fieldnamecheck != -1) {
                        if (fldObj.checked) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    function CheckForm11(f) {
        var email_re = /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/i;
        if (!email_re.test(f.email.value)) {
            alert("Por favor ingresá tu EMAIL CORECTAMENTE y luego chequeá que el TELÉFONO sea también correcto. Luego presioná el botón naranja. Estás a sólo 1 paso de ahorrar el 70% en tu compra!");
            f.email.focus();
            return false;
        }

            return true;
        }

// ]]>
```

So the question is: how can I integrate this second script into the first one to make it all work?

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery form plugin might help you. Here's the section on validation:

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#validation